# How to read .net xml serialized datetimes from java?

Tags: c#, java, datetime

I am porting some of our app from c# to java.  Some data objects get xml serialized and stored for later use.  The built in .net xml serialization automatically saves DateTime properties in the format below:

```
2009-05-11T16:47:08.6033346-04:00
```

How can I get this into a Date object in Java?  I read that the date format is ISO 8601 which labled as SortableDateTime in the MSDN documentation.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, this format is specified for use in XML documents by the W3C Schema spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime It's not just something .NET happens to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following snippet:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date d = sdf.parse("2009-05-11T16:47:08.6033346-04:00");
```

Answer (score 1):

[`parseDateTime`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29)?